# How to get 4th value from array swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I am  trying to get 4th items from the arrays. These given below array:

```
let mainArray = ["1", "2", "3", "7", "10", "4", "5", "6", "9", "12", "16", "11", "13", "14", "15"]
let valueCheck = "3"

//check value present or not in array

if mainArray.contains(valueCheck){

    //if yes print next value from match value
    Let valuePresent = self.mainArray.index(after: Int(valueCheck)!)
    print(valuePresent)
}
```

> output = "4"
>
> but i want "7"

When i am trying to above code to get 4th value they give me 4th index but i want 4th index value.

Can someone please explain to me how to solve this, i've tried to solve this but no results yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `mainArray[3]`?

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID107

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
let mainArray = ["1", "2", "3", "7", "10", "4", "5", "6", "9", "12", "16", "11", "13", "14", "15"]
let valueCheck = "3" // index for this is 2

//check value present or not in array
if let index = mainArray.firstIndex(of: valueCheck){
    let value = mainArray[index + 1]
    print(value)
}
```

While this will work, if for example, you want the item after "15", `valueCheck = "15"` this will crash.

You can prevent this by extending collection with:

```
extension Collection {

    subscript(safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        return return index < endIndex && index >= startIndex ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

And then update your code with:

```
let mainArray = ["1", "2", "3", "7", "10", "4", "5", "6", "9", "12", "16", "11", "13", "14", "15"]
let valueCheck = "3" // index for this is 2

//check value present or not in array
if let index = mainArray.firstIndex(of: valueCheck){
    let value = mainArray[safe: index + 1]
    print(value)
}
```

Comment: `index < endIndex` or even `index < endIndex && index >= startIndex` is more efficient than `indices.contains(index)`

Comment: Nicely spotted @vadian :)

Answer (score 0):

> First you have to check whether index is not out of bound then you can get the value via Array `Subscript` like below

```
let mainArray = ["1", "2", "3", "7", "10", "4", "5", "6", "9", "12", "16", "11", "13", "14", "15"]
let valueCheck = "3"

if let index = Int(valueCheck) {
if mainArray.count > index {
     let result = mainArray[index]
 }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: thank you but your ans give me total count, but i want 4th index value

Comment: Why `mainArray.count > value` this ??

Comment: @Sham can you print value of result like print("Result: \(result)") , what value your are getting ?

Comment: @dahiya_boy if index is out of the bound of mainArray then it will crash if we will directly access via index. for example if you execute this statement mainArray[15] then it will crash  so i added check to avoid the crash.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasBhati It's bcz you have written `mainArray[value]`. Its never happen you got array with the same index values like you are using. You have to find out the index of value in array. If you do this  **IndexOutOfBound** never happen. Right now check your code for array `["105", "110", "200", "224", "89","119"]` and check does you got same response for `110` element.

Comment: @dahiya_boy sorry I have given wrong variable name but my logic is correct, edit my answer.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasBhati Bro pls check other answers. Your answer still same. Btw its wrong and not a good practice.

Comment: `String` value in constant `valueCheck` is not an index value rather an element inside the array. You are converting an array element's value to `Integer` for index to find the required value, which is wrong. You should fin the index for that value using Array's helper methods and then access the required element with help of that index.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the index of the third element and that is "7" 
because the array starts with the index of zero

```
let mainArray = ["1", "2", "3", "7", "10", "4", "5", "6", "9", "12", "16", "11", "13", "14", "15"]
let valueCheck = "7" // index for this is 3

//check value present or not in array

if mainArray.contains(valueCheck){

//if yes print next value from match value
Let valuePresent = self.mainArray.index(after: Int(valueCheck)!)

let output = mainArray[valuePresent]
print(output) // the output will be 10

}
```

Comment: No, the output is 8. You are mixing up *index* and *object at index* like the OP.

Comment: yes, you are right i forgot to get the output by the index. @vadian

Answer (score 0):

```
let mainArray = ["1", "2", "3", "7", "10", "4", "5", "6", "9", "12", "16", "11", "13", "14", "15"]
let valueCheck = "3"

//check value present or not in array

if mainArray.contains(valueCheck){

    //if yes print next value from match value
    let checkedValueindex = mainArray.firstIndex(of: valueCheck)
    let valuePresentIndex = mainArray.index(after: checkedValueindex!)
    print(mainArray[valuePresentIndex])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let mainArray = ["1", "2", "3", "7", "10", "4", "5", "6", "9", "12", "16", "11", "13", "14", "15"]

if mainArray.indices.contains(3) {
    let value = mainArray[3]
    print(value)
}

This code will help you.